# Passing data to Quick Books Online from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, quickbooks

I'm working on MVC Application. All I need is a way to upload customer information from this web application to QuickBooks Online. Following steps I've performed already:-

1) Created trial account in Quick-books online.

2) Registered myself in developer.intuit.com.

3) Went through documentation provided in the "developer" site itself, which provided me some bunch of code in c#.

4) I got a link in the net i.e. http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1396 which provides certain different links to get the consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret etc.

I have realm ID with me. Question is how can i get the App Token?

Also there is no such clear procedure in the web, how can i connect to the QBO. It seems I need to create some APP & publish the same, to which MVC application will connect & that will connect to QBO company.

Is it possible to perform upload data on QBO without creating & publishing any app on developer.intuit.com?

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance

SinghN

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. The link i mentioned above (in the question) - I simply created an account in the Sandbox account. & then i got all the required values i.e. consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, appToken, realmID.

I was wondering if there's any other way to integrate with the online Quick-Books edition. However I ended up the following way :-

Creating an app in the online account, which provided us "App Token" Keys. Instructions provided in the link i.e. http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1396 helped to get the rest of the keys defined above.

In other words, .Net application integrates with these app (created by us in the Quick-books online edition) & then app integrates with the Quick-books account.